# why router is undefined in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

could you please tell me why router is undefined in react js .I already import react-router.js file in my codepen

here is my code
http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/pymqPa?editors=1010

```
class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <Router>
          <Route path='/' component={first}></Route>
         <Route path='/about' component={second}></Route>
        </Router>
    }

}

class second extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <label>second component</label>
    }

}
class first extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <label>first component</label>
    }

}

React.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router#installation), when you include the library via a `<script>` tag, the library will be available on `window.ReactRouter`.

You can add at the top of your file the following assignment:

```
{ Router } = ReactRouter;
```

This will expose the `Router` component from `react-router` to a variable `Router`, which is what your code expects.

Comment: please see my setting file .I imported that ,,

Comment: but still it not display first component http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/KzLJqE?editors=1010

Comment: It may be because you are trying to use the deprecated `React.render()` method instead of `ReactDOM`. See the docs for more info: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

Comment: Please clarify above what error you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use BrowserRouter (react-router-dom) package instead of Router. Your code would look something like this :

```
<div>
<ReactRouter.Route path='/' component={first}></ReactRouter.Route>
<ReactRouter.Route path='/about' component={second}></ReactRouter.Route>
</div>
```

Also Notice div tag in ReactRouter otherwise you will get "A Router may have only one child element" error.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to brace your returned JSX:

```
return (
  <Router>
    <Route path='/' component={first}></Route>
    <Route path='/about' component={second}></Route>
  </Router>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialise the aliases when script tag is dropped.

Try something like:

```
var Router  = window.ReactRouter;
var Route  = window.ReactRouter.Ruote;
```

At the beginning of your code